# What other options are there apart from localnet in dnsmasq?

Tags: 10.04, internet, dnsmasq

I was wondering if DNSMASQ had any other options in it's configuration files than localnet?

I would like to define a DNS Server to use in the DNSMASQ configuration file.

Rather like this:

```
    $server=/internet/8.8.8.8
```

I am not sure if this would work. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are also using dnsmasq as your DHCP server, you can configure dnsmasq to send a list of DNS servers to the clients. For example, this line in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` sends the primary DNS as 10.0.0.1 and Google's Public DNS servers as secondary and tertiary:

> dhcp-option=6,10.0.0.1,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Comment: Is it needed to have the 6, in the line? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the 6 specifies a feature of the DHCP protocol to use. For example, 1 is to specify netmask, 3 is gateway, 6 is DNS servers, 42 is NTP server. Read the comments around the dhcp-option lines in the dnsmasq.conf for some more info on them.